# CosmosDb query complex structure: sub totals

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In my collection i have such documents

```
{
    "purchase_order_number": "PO15428132600",
    "total_due": 4893.3929,
    "account_number": "Account2",
    "freight": 183.1626,
    "ttl": 2592000,
    "order_date": "Mon Jul 11 00:00:00 2005",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "subtotal": 6107.082,
    "id": "SalesOrder",
    "_ts": 1519575296,
    "items": [
      {
        "line_price": 5.7,
        "order_qty": 3,
        "currecny_code": "USD",
        "unit_price": 17.1,
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "product_code": "A-123",
        "product_name": "Product 1"
      },
      {
        "line_price": 4.7,
        "order_qty": 4,
        "currecny_code": "USD",
        "unit_price": 15,
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "product_code": "A-123",
        "product_name": "Product 1"
      },
      {
        "line_price": 1.7,
        "order_qty": 2,
        "currecny_code": "USD",
        "unit_price": 5.1,
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "product_code": "A-123",
        "product_name": "Product 1"
      }
    ]
}
```

I don't know if it is possible i'm beginner with Cosmo ( but background in relationnal databases)

I'd like to be able to do a query that gives me the sum ( unit_price * order_qty) from my items , that i could place in a UDF

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT SUM(item.unit_price * item.order_qty) FROM item IN o.items
```

Or if you need to filter on orders, and sum over items, use the `JOIN` clause to unwind the array.

```
SELECT SUM(item.unit_price * item.order_qty) 
FROM order 
JOIN item IN order.items 
WHERE order.purchase_order_number = "PO15428132600"
```

Comment: Thanks.Calling the second query in python enabling cross partition query gives me "Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggreateFunc>' for aggregates. . I will try to store the query as UDF if possible